# The Linux 'ls' command and directory privileges - "cannot access /tmp/restricted/foo*: No such file or directory"

Tags: sudo, ls

Why does one command work and the other doesn’t?  I have found some remotely related articles, but I failed to understand them.

```
$ sudo ls -la /tmp/restricted
total 12
drwxr-x---.  2 root root    42 Mar 17 17:40 .
drwxrwxrwt. 12 root root 12288 Mar 17 17:37 ..
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 root tms      0 Mar 17 17:22 foo1
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 root tms      0 Mar 17 17:22 foo2
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 root tms      0 Mar 17 17:22 foo3

$ sudo ls -a /tmp/restricted/foo*
ls: cannot access /tmp/restricted/foo*: No such file or directory
```

Note that if I change the privileges on /tmp/restricted to 755 instead of 750, both commands succeed:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /tmp/restricted/

$ sudo ls -la /tmp/restricted
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    42 Mar 17 17:40 .
drwxrwxrwt. 12 root root 12288 Mar 17 17:37 ..
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 root tms      0 Mar 17 17:22 foo1
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 root tms      0 Mar 17 17:22 foo2
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 root tms      0 Mar 17 17:22 foo3

$ sudo ls -a /tmp/restricted/foo*
/tmp/restricted/foo1  /tmp/restricted/foo2  /tmp/restricted/foo3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run `sudo ls -la /tmp/restricted`, `ls` runs as root and has full access to `/tmp/restricted`.

When you run `sudo ls -a /tmp/restricted/foo*`, your shell, which is not running as root, attempts to expand `/tmp/restricted/foo*`. It can’t, and in your case leaves the argument alone. `ls` runs as root, with an argument of `/tmp/restricted/foo*`, and since no file exists with that name, fails with the error message you’re seeing.

You can see the same error by forcing your shell not to glob: `ls "*"` (unless you have a file really named `*` in the current directory).

Comment: @heuvy6 a simple solution would be: `sudo sh -c 'ls -a /tmp/restricted/foo*'`, which will force the `*` to expand inside root's shell.